# Getting the namespace of a ProjectItem

Tags: c#, vsix, envdte

I'm writing a VSIX extension that extends `IModelGenerationExtension` which does some things after an Entity Data Model is updated or generated.

```
public class ModelGenerationExtension : IModelGenerationExtension
{
    public void OnAfterModelGenerated(ModelGenerationExtensionContext context)
    {
    }
    public void OnAfterModelUpdated(UpdateModelExtensionContext context)
    {
        //need namespace of context.ProjectItem here
    }
}
```

Since this is operating on an entity data model, the `context.ProjectItem` will be an .edmx file - let's call this `Model1.edmx`. This will contain a file named `Model1.tt` which in turn has some nested *.cs* files each associated to an entity.

What I need to do is get the namespace of one of these .cs files (all entities will be on the same namespace) from the `ProjectItem`.

[image]

How can I go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a while ago since I developed a VS extension, but I looked at some of my old code on how to search for those things. Maybe there are newer technologies today, but this is what I know:

At first you should find the correct file by iterating through the child `ProjectItems` of the item you got for your `Model1.edmx` to find the *.cs files:

```
ProjectItem tt = context.ProjectItem.ProjectItems.OfType<ProjectItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name == "Model1.tt");

ProjectItem cs = tt.ProjectItems.OfType<ProjectItem>()
                        .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Name.EndsWith(".cs"));
```

Then you could use the `FileCodeModel` of this `ProjectItem cs` to search for the first namespace configuration:

```
CodeNamespace nsp = cs.FileCodeModel.CodeElements.Cast<CodeElement>().
            OfType<CodeNamespace>().First();
```

And there you should have your namespace element. `CodeNamespace` has a property `Name` and a `FullName`.

I put this together from what I read in my old codes, but could not test it right now. You need to add error handling and I'm not 100% sure that the files hierarchy as you described it is really reproduced like that in the `ProjectItems` hierarchy.